# How do I get new web site as project in VB using visual studio 2008

Tags: vb.net

I started VS 2008 with VB as language. New project I clicked web but son't see new web site as an option. I am trying to chose new web site then new web service but they don't show up as one of my choices.

I have repaired VS 2008 professional and chose everything under VB. Now when I click web the only options I see are.

```
ASP.NET Web Application
ASP.NET AJAX Server Control
ASP.NET Web Service Application
ASP.NET Ajax Server Control Extender
WCF Service Application.
```

Any ideas on how to get new web site added to my option for project type.

Comment: web projects are generally better unless you need to edit the files in production, instead of deploying them, or you project is too big to build before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was clicking File > new project. Had I clicked File > New Web Site it works.